# Removing data from database

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I am designing a booking system and i need to know how would you remove an appointment (so it no longer displays) from the database when another user has already taken up that appointment.

```
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "" or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.Doctor_name, t2.Doctor_room FROM Appointment AS t1 INNER JOIN Doctor AS t2 ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

    //this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    

    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_name'] = $row['Doctor_name'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_room'] = $row['Doctor_room'];
    }
}
```

The code above currently allows users to book an appointment. I need the time and date to not display if it has been taken.

Thanks!

Comment: which field are you using to mark if the appointment is taken or not ..and in which table and please correct your first line it is supposed to be `mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());` ?

Comment: The [mysql_*](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) extensions have been deprecated, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: show my your sql structure for the table  `Appointment `

Answer (score 0):

You shold have a boolean field in table Appointment table to mark it as taken or not .. I assume it as `'Appointment_taken`...if this is 0 then the appointment is still to be taken ..

Then you can check the condition as follows

```
            <?php
        {
            mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


            $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); 
            $query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.Doctor_name, t2.Doctor_room ".
                     "FROM Appointment AS t1 INNER JOIN Doctor AS t2 ".
                     "ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id";

            //executes query on the database
            $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

            //this selects the results as rows
            $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    

            //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
            if ($num == 1)
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                if($row['Appointment_taken'] == 0 )
                {
                    $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
                    $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
                }

                $_SESSION['Doctor_name']      = $row['Doctor_name'];
                $_SESSION['Doctor_room']      = $row['Doctor_room'];
            }
        }

        ?>
```

And as others have suggested you you should start learning PDO and mysqli